# Mount windows network folder in linux [debian]

Tags: linux, networking, mount, samba, cifs

I've got a Windows Server 2016 with a VM Host running a Domain Controller, Exchange Server and a 3CX-Server. The ladder is a linux server running Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u2. I've got the folder `C:/PCAP` which I shared in the network (`\\ta-vm\PCAP` or `\\192.168.X.X\PCAP` I rather don't specify the full IP-Address).

I created a new folder `/mnt/PCAP/` and would like to mount the network folder into this folder.

After that I ran the following code to mount the network folder:

`sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.X.X/PCAP /mnt/PCAP/ -o username=Administrator`.

This gives me the following output: `Unable to find suitable address.`

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Maybe someone can enlighten me on this subject.

Comment: It says *Unable to find suitable address* because *192.168.X.X* is not a suitable address.

Comment: Install the `smbclient` package and try running `smbclient -U Administrator -L //ta-vm` and `smbclient -U Administrator -L //192.168.X.X` (I really assume you have sensible numbers in place of those `X`s, do you?). That command connects to the named host and asks it via the Windows RPC about which shares the machine has. If that works, the command *should* work, and the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Also, as usually [searching the 'net for the exact error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=cifs+"Unable+to+find+suitable+address") yields lots of useful stuff, including [this suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/325218/43156) which is like mine but suggests adding the `-d3` command-line option to `smbclient` to make it output (more) debugging information. JFTR, the problem in *that* case was with tight firewall rules preventing traffic on the standard CIFS ports.

Comment: …and while we're at it, please consider not using the `username` and `password` options to `mount.cifs` as everything which gets passed on the command-line is insecure by default on Unix'y systems where each user can freely monitor the list of running processes; use the `credentials` option instead—along with the file with tight permissions.

Comment: I was just simply using the wrong IP-Address for this case ... I should have sooner called it a day yesterday.